# Deletar apenas linhas com checkbox selecionado em uma JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Como deletar de uma `JTable` as linhas que forem marcadas em um CheckBox que está em uma célula da tabela? Estou utilizando `AbstractTableModel`.

O código que consegui criar, apaga apenas parte dos registros selecionados, sempre sobra algum.

Criei um código simples com a simulação do problema:

Teste

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;    
public class Teste extends JFrame{
       //MAIN METHOD
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {

           EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
           {
               public void run()
               {
                   //INITIALIZE JFRAME FORM
                   teste.Teste form=new teste.Teste();
                   form.setVisible(true);;
               }
           });

      }

      private JTextField txtId;

      TesteTableModel tableModel = new TesteTableModel();
      private final JTable table;

      //CONSTRUCTOR
      public Teste()
      {
            setLayout(null);
            setSize(794, 548);

            JLabel lblListaDePendencias = new JLabel("Lista de Pend\u00EAncias:");
            lblListaDePendencias.setBounds(10, 11, 120, 14);
            add(lblListaDePendencias);

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setBounds(10, 31, 774, 380);
            add(panel);
            panel.setLayout(null);

            table = new JTable(tableModel);
            table.setBounds(0, 0, 774, 380);
            panel.add(table);

            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
            scrollPane.setBounds(0, 0, 774, 380);
            panel.add(scrollPane);

            table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);

            JButton btnRemoverPendencias = new JButton("Remover");
            btnRemoverPendencias.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    tableModel.deletarLinhas();
                }
            });
            btnRemoverPendencias.setBounds(10, 422, 157, 23);
             add(btnRemoverPendencias);

             TesteModel t1 = new TesteModel();
             t1.setSelecionado(false);
             t1.setNome("Pedro");

             TesteModel t2 = new TesteModel();
             t2.setSelecionado(false);
             t2.setNome("Maria");

             TesteModel t3 = new TesteModel();
             t3.setSelecionado(false);
             t3.setNome("João");

             TesteModel t4 = new TesteModel();
             t4.setSelecionado(false);
             t4.setNome("Helena");

             TesteModel t5 = new TesteModel();
             t5.setSelecionado(false);
             t5.setNome("Lúcia");

             tableModel.addRow(t1);
             tableModel.addRow(t2);
             tableModel.addRow(t3);
             tableModel.addRow(t4);
             tableModel.addRow(t5);

      }
    }
```

classe model

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

    public class TesteModel {
        private Boolean selecionado;
        private String nome;

        public Boolean getSelecionado() {
            return selecionado;
        }

        public void setSelecionado(Boolean selecionado) {
            this.selecionado = selecionado;
        }

        public String getNome() {
            return nome;
        }

        public void setNome(String nome) {
            this.nome = nome;
        }

    }
```

Classe TableModel

```
public class TesteTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {


    private List<TesteModel> dados = new ArrayList<>();
    private String[] colunas = {"Selecionar", "Nome"};


    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return columnIndex == 0 ? Boolean.class : super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column){
        return colunas[column];
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return colunas.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return dados.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int linha, int coluna) {
        switch(coluna){
            case 0:
                return dados.get(linha).getSelecionado();
            case 1:
                return dados.get(linha).getNome();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void setValueAt(Object valor, int linha, int coluna) {
        TesteModel tm = dados.get(linha);
        switch (coluna) {
        case 0:
            tm.setSelecionado(new Boolean((Boolean) valor));
            break;
        }
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    public void addRow(TesteModel tm) {
        this.dados.add(tm);
        this.fireTableDataChanged();    
    }

    public void removeRow(int linha){
        this.dados.remove(linha);
        this.fireTableRowsDeleted(linha, linha);
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                    return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    public void deletarLinhas() {
        for (int i = 0; i < dados.size(); i++) {
            if(dados.get(i).getSelecionado()) {
                dados.remove(i); //Remove o aluno da lista
                fireTableRowsDeleted(i, i); //Informa a tabela
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Lys, sempre adicione os imports junto ao codigo, eles fazem parte tambem.

Comment: Certo, adicionados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recomendação é que, ao deletar de forma massiva linhas de uma `JTable`, se faça de forma decrescente nos indices, pois a cada deleção, o indice da lista de objetos dela é atualizado, e isso causa alguns bugs como este de não deletar todos os itens.

Altere para:

```
public void deletarLinhas() {
    
    for (int i = getRowCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        if (dados.get(i).getSelecionado()) {
            removeRow(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Outra dica é não duplicar ações, sua classe já possui um método de remover linhas individuais, que é o `removeRow()`, se quer remover linha por linha, basta chamar este método e passar o índice para ele. A mesma dica vale para o tamanho da lista, procure sempre optar pela forma mais abstraida possivel, isso facilita não só o entendimento e a manutenção, como evita adição de código duplicado e desnecessário.

Com essa modificação, o código funciona normalmente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Outra dica é esse método `isCellEditable()`, criar um switch apenas para validar uma condição é, novamente, desperdicio de código. Isso pode ser simplficado em apenas uma linha, sem deixar de ser legível:

```
public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        
    return columnIndex == 0; 
}
```

Também vale ressaltar a recomendação abaixo:

> **Evite usar layout absoluto, a não ser que seja de extrema necessidade e que saiba as consequências disso**, pois layout absoluto dificulta manutenção da tela e faz com que sua aplicação fique com aparência diferente dependendo do monitor e resolução que estiver sendo executada.
>
> Existem vários [**gerenciadores de layouts**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) para que você não tenha que se preocupar com posicionamento ou organização manual de componentes. Sem contar que o uso de layouts faz com que seu código fique mais fácil de dar manutenção do que ficar inserindo um monte de `setbounds`, e caso precise alterar a posição de algum componente, no layout absoluto, vai ter que reposicionar todos manualmente.

Comment: Nossa, tão simples! Já havia tentando várias abordagens mas não decrescente. Agradeço  muito por isso e também pelas dicas de melhorias, vou levar todas em consideração.

Comment: @lys disponha :)